# F# compilation error

Tags: f#

I am a newbie in F# and I encounter an error in the following function:

```
let PrintBoard (board:list<string>) (size:int) :unit =
    for i = 0 to (size - 1) do
        printf " ---"
    printfn ""
    for i = 0 to (size - 1) do 
        printf "| "
        for j = 0 to (size -1) do // error: "The value is not a function and cannot be applied"
            printf "%s" (List.item(i * size + j) board)
            printf " | "
            done
        printfn ""
    done
    for i = 0 to (size - 1) do
        printf " ---"
    printfn ""
```

I don't understand why I can't use "size" in the nested loop.

Comment: Not having used F# (but having used Lisp) I would guess that `(size -1)` looks like a function call. I think you need `(size - 1)` (note the space).

Comment: Hmm, that was it. It didn't even cross my mind... Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool, I will post an answer.

Comment: @minime - Since cdhowie's answer was the correct one, you should "accept" it by clicking the checkbox under his answer (on the left, just under the vote-up / vote-down buttons). That will let others who find this question later know that it received a correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was looking for the "accept" button and didn't realise it was the "tick" image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax `(size -1)` attempts to call the function `size` and pass it the argument `-1`, but `size` isn't a function (hence, "the value is not a function").  You need to use `(size - 1)` instead -- note the space!

Comment: In terms of formal grammar ([see spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/)), you want the expression `size -1` to be parsed as _expr infix-op expr_, not as _expr expr_ ie. function application; hence, `size-1` -- note no space -- would also work. Here, the parentheses have no bearing on the analysis.